# Как отслеживать изменения Settings_fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня есть settings_fragment. Вот его layout

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/settings_layout">

<PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/messages_header">

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:key="switch_cheating"
        app:title="@string/enable_cheating" />

    <EditTextPreference
        app:key="cheating_text"
        app:title="@string/cheat_number"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/history_header">

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:key="switch_history"
        app:title="@string/enable_history" />

</PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/dark_theme">

    <SwitchPreferenceCompat
        app:key="switch_theme"
        app:title="@string/enable_theme" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

Также у меня есть SettinsFragment.kt

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences)
}
```

}

MainActivity.kt (активити, которому принадлежит фрагмент)

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var navController: NavController

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    navController =
        (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host) as NavHostFragment).navController
}
```

}

В итоге, как мне получить в MainActivity лисенеры, сообщающие о переключении чего-то в Settigs_fragment?

Comment: Как-то так: `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(yourListener)`

Comment: а что такое yourListener?

Comment: Это ваша реализация интерфейса [`SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener)

Comment: Не очень понимаю. Мне надо строчку кода PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(yourListener) засунуть в OnCreate MainActivity? И что значит реализация интерфейса? Получается мне надо сначала в OnCreate засунуть строчку PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(yourListener), и создать (до этой строчки) интерфейс val yourListener. Так?

Comment: Я не пишу на котлине, могу показать пример только на java. В активности нужно объявить поле и присвоить ему реализацию интерфейса. В `onCreate` зарегистрировать.  Так же при закрытии активности лучше отписаться от листенера вызовом `unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener()`

Comment: Ну покажите, пожалуйста, пример на Java. Java и kotlin похожи, думаю смогу на kotlin переписать

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58258252/15923106 - вот пример на котлине (немного другой, там сама активность реализует интерфейс листенера, но думаю вам это не важно)

Comment: Кажется это то что мне нужно. Сейчас я проверю

Comment: Да, спасибо большое. Вы меня спасли